# Why does operator in piped Subject is called for every subscription?

Tags: rxjs, pipe, subject

I need to filter values from Subject and do some side-effects on returned data.
Something like this:

```
const subject2 = subject.pipe(
  filter((value: number) => {
    console.log(`filter: ${value}`);
    return value % 2 === 0; // filter even nubmers
  }),
  tap((value) => console.log(`after filter: ${value}`))
);
```

I see that function from `filter()` is called for every value emitted to `subject2` subscribers (i.e. as many times as `subject2` subscribers length). But I assumed that it will be called once for every `next()` call.

Also I see that if I subscribe to `subject2` and pipe its values, no duplication appears.

Could someone please explain what's going on behind the scene and what is the correct pattern of filtering subject values?

Example on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-e4stc4?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts

Comment: Every `subscribe()` call makes a new chain with its own `filter()`. If you wanted to avoid that you could share the source Observable with `share()` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the Subject's `next` method is implemented like this:

```
for (const observer of this.observers) {
  observer.next(value);
}
```

So each "observer" (or "subscriber") will get its own notification when you emit into the Subject. The operators are just functions that process the `value` before the result is passed to the observer.

For example if you declared the operators like this:

```
const myFilter = filter((value: number) => value % 2 === 0);
const myTap = tap((value) => console.log(`after filter: ${value}`));
```

Then the `next` function inside a custom Subject could be implemented like this:

```
for (const observer of this.observers) {
  observer.next(myTap(myFilter(value)));
}
```

(This code wouldn't actually work - it's a simplification to show how the values reach the subscriber when you call `next` on a Subject)

To solve your issue, you can reduce the number of observers to the source Subject by putting a `share()` as the last element of the chain like so:

```
const subject2 = subject.pipe(
  filter((value: number) => {
    console.log(`filter: ${value}`);
    return value % 2 === 0; // filter even nubmers
  }),
  tap((value) => console.log(`after filter: ${value}`)),
  share()
);
```

`share` is implemented such that it acts as a single observer to the source Observable no matter how many observers are subscribed to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! And the solution you've suggested is worked. I liked the illustration of how operators are applied to the value. Because I thought about it like this (ha-ha):

`value = myTap(myFilter(value));`  
`for (const observer of this.observers) { `  
`  observer.next(value);`  
`}`

Now will try to understand how share() operator works :D